# The Laplacian operator of $\;{ {\zeta}_0}^2+{ {\zeta}_1}^2=1\;$

Tags: functional-analysis, laplacian, differential-operators

> Let $\;\Delta\;$ be the Laplacian operator in $\;\mathbb R^n\;$ and
>   consider two functions $\;{\zeta}_0 \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb
>  R^n),{\zeta}_1 \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)\;$ such that $\;{
>  {\zeta}_0}^2+{ {\zeta}_1}^2=1\;$.
>
> Then a simple computation shows: $\;\Delta =
>  {\zeta}_{0}\Delta{\zeta}_{0}+{\vert \nabla {\zeta}_{0}
>  \vert}^2+{\zeta}_{1}\Delta{\zeta}_{1}+{\vert \nabla {\zeta}_{1}
>  \vert}^2\;$ where the functions here are taken as multiplication operators.

The above is a part of a proof I'm reading at the moment. Although the computation is a simple one, I have trouble deducing the above equality. What I see is:

$\;\Delta = \Delta(1)=\Delta({ {\zeta}_0}^2+{ {\zeta}_1}^2)=2({\zeta}_{0}\Delta{\zeta}_{0}+{\vert \nabla {\zeta}_{0}
 \vert}^2+{\zeta}_{1}\Delta{\zeta}_{1}+{\vert \nabla {\zeta}_{1}
 \vert}^2)\;$

What am I missing here? Any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is that quote from?

Comment: Is there a link to the whole proof?

Comment: It is a part of a proof of a lemma which is used in order to prove the formula for the bottom of the essential spectrum of a Schrodinger operator. Unfortunately I couldn't find this paper online. Is it necessary to add it in my post?

Comment: normally on the left side it should be zero since $\Delta (1)=0$.

Comment: @Arian So the number 2 in my computation vanishes, is that what you say? I thought about that too but I wasn't sure if it's correct.

Comment: yes you can omit $2$.

Comment: @Arian but then shouldn't the expression in the proof be $\;{\zeta}_{0}\Delta{\zeta}_{0}+{\vert \nabla {\zeta}_{0}
 \vert}^2+{\zeta}_{1}\Delta{\zeta}_{1}+{\vert \nabla {\zeta}_{1}
 \vert}^2\;=0\;$?

Comment: @kaithkolesidou That's what it looks like. But without knowing the exact context, it's had to judge. There might be a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=1$ it is probably easier to see. In this case $$\Delta:=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$$
Thus
$$\Delta (\zeta_1^2+\zeta_2^2)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\zeta_1^2+\zeta_2^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(2\zeta_1\zeta_1'+2\zeta_2\zeta_2')=2(\zeta_1\zeta''_1+(\zeta'_1)^2+\zeta_2\zeta_2''+(\zeta_2')^2)$$
On the other hand
$$\Delta(1)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(1)=0$$
Therefore $$\zeta_1\zeta''_1+(\zeta'_1)^2+\zeta_2\zeta_2''+(\zeta_2')^2=0$$
For general $n>1$ it holds
$$\zeta_1\Delta\zeta_1+|\nabla\zeta_1|^2+\zeta_2\Delta\zeta_2+|\nabla\zeta_2|^2=0$$
where $$\Delta:=\frac{d^2}{dx_1^2}+...+\frac{d^2}{dx_n^2}$$
and $\nabla$ is the gradient.